# Spark driver file server returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: file, http, apache-spark, server, authorization

Using Spark 1.6.1, the driver starts a http file server on a random port, which the workers are supposed to access to fetch jars. In my setup, the workers are getting a 401 unauthorized from the file server, when attempting to fetch the jars. Any idea on how authorization is configured on this file server on the driver?

Driver code is in Scala using SparkConf to set jars like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("myApp")
.setMaster(masterUrl)
.set("spark.task.maxFailures", "1")
.set("spark.executor.memory", sparkExecutorMemory)     
.set("spark.metrics.conf.driver.sink.jmx.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink")
.set("spark.authenticate", "true")
.set("spark.authenticate.secret", secret)
.setJars(jarsInClasspath)

val sc: SparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
sc.parallelize(myCollection).map (myFunc).collect
```

spark.authenticate is configured on all three: master, driver and slaves, with the same secret

On worker, I see these two errors:

```
Fetching http://11.163.0.285:51712/jars/libSetPluginTypes.jar with timestamp 1476207005509

java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
```

and after a while, this:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Cannot assign requested address
```

Looking at the tcpdump on the driver:

```
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /jars/libSetPluginTypes.jar. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

Please note that this whole thing works if I manually put the jars on the slave's classpath, and not do the setJars on the driver side.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!